# Laravel 5: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, properties

I'm get:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\posts.blade.php)

Error in these lines:

```
@if($post->id === Auth::user()->id)
<br><a href="#">Redaguoti</a>
@endif
```

All code:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-body" rel="#author{{ $topics->author_id }}">
    <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $topics->title }}</h4>
  </div>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="{{ generateProfileURL($post->name, $post->id) }}">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://localhost/uploads/avatars/{{ $post->avatar_id }}.{{ $post->avatar_end }}" style="width: 64px">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body" rel="#post{{ $post->pid }}">
  <a href="{{ generateProfileURL($post->name, $post->id) }}">{{ $post->name }}</a><br>{{ $post->text }}
  @if($post->id == Auth::user()->id)
  <br><a href="#">Edit</a>
  @endif
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
{!! $posts->render() !!}
@stop
```

Thanks in advance ;)

**EDIT** That's because I'm not logged in :D

Comment: Either `$post` isn't an object, or the user isn't logged in, so `Auth::user()` is returning null. Can you show us what you're passing to the view for `$posts` ?

Comment: @Ben yep, I'm not logged in, thanks ;)

Comment: OK, I posted that as the answer then -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Either `$post` isn't an object, or the user isn't logged in, so `Auth::user()` is returning `null`.

To remove the error, check first if the user is logged in before running that section of code:

```
@if (Auth::check())

     // put auth-only code here

     @if($post->id === Auth::user()->id)
         <br><a href="#">Redaguoti</a>
     @endif

@endif
```

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, I will mark is at answer after 10min, because now I can't

Answer (score 0):

There are several instances you can get this error,

1. When your response needs an authenticated user to access as your case might be and
2. When you are returning an object but you're accessing it as an array either using foreach, or forelse.

You have to check with all diligence what data you're returning and the respective methods accordingly